# The Imperial Legion is mad at Lydia. What do I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just completed the Battle for Whiterun, and, as per my playstyle, I dismissed Lydia once that was done. When I dismissed her, the Legion (the side I fought for) started attacking her. What can I do to keep Lydia from dying and/or killing everyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After messing with various console commands, I figured out one way to solve it. I added Lydia to the Imperial Legion faction with the following console commands:

```
prid A2C94
addfac 2BF9A 1
```

I also had to use `resetai` on everyone involved (I opted to just `kill` a few of them) to make everyone put their weapons away.